# Is there a way to draw an ellipse around a pin location on OpenStreetMap with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, scale, openstreetmap, marker, ellipse

I want to make an ellipse around a user's pin location (OpenStreetMap, Flutter) that has a certain height, width, and angle. The height and width should be to scale with the map and not the screen (eg in some unit of distance, like meters). I can draw a circle using the CircleMarker class as that has an argument useRadiusInMeter, but I'm not able to find something similar for drawing an ellipse. I can only find options such as BoxDecoration or CustomPainter but there is no provision for converting to distance units. Is it possible to define an ellipse in terms of the map scale?

For reference, I want something like this:
[image]

Comment: Do you want to make a circle like this in a map?

Comment: Yes, but I want to make an ellipse (with specific height, width and angle with axis as shown in the picture). I am able to make a circle using the CircleMarker class, but not an ellipse.

Comment: you can use clipoval where you can use customclipper [clipoval](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzWWDO6whIM)